# Using a Citrix server to host an Access database frontend allowing faster access for geographically separated users

Tags: ms-access, citrix

My situation is that I have an Access database that needs to be shared in real-time with users separated geographically, i.e., Alaska, Hawaii, Korea.  The database has a frontend that will be, once the server is purchased, connected to a MS SQL Server backend.  User on the same LAN segment as the server (Hawaii) will have no problems with accessing the data, or the resulting speed; however, trying to set it up to when the remote users access the live data over an http connection from all across the Pacific Rim will be an exercise in futility.  I am wondering about the feasibility, and practicality, of setting up a Citrix server on the same machine as the SQL server backend in order to host the frontend application allowing remote users to access and interact with the database frontend via a Citrix client.  Unfortunately, I have very little knowledge about Citrix other than being an end-user on the client side.  Is Citrix a viable option for this scenario or is there a better way to provide access to these remote users at a reasonable speed?  I would prefer to not have to build a web client for a frontend as this would be a huge undertaking.  Thanks in advance.
Billy

Answer (score 0):

Using Citrix XenApp is a viable option. Citrix works well in scenarios where centralized data needs to be accessed from remote locations.

Setting up XenApp is not trivial, though. You might find interesting reading material in my article [XenApp Reading List](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/11/xenapp-reading-list/).